# awk greater than why show string value?

Tags: awk

I am using this command

```
awk  '$1 > 3 {print $1}' file;
```

file :

```
String
2 
4
5
6
7
String
```

output this;

```
String
4
5
6
7
String
```

Why result does not been only numbers as below,

```
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because one side of the comparison is a string, so awk is doing string comparison and the numeric value of the character 'S' is greater than 3.

```
$ printf "3: %d S: %d\n" \'3 \'S
3: 51 S: 83
```

Note: the `'` before the arguments passed to `printf` are important, as they trigger the [conversion to the numeric value in the underlying codeset](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html):

> If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.

We write `\'` so that the `'` is passed to `printf`, rather than being interpreted as syntax by the shell (a plain `'` would open/close a string literal).

---

Returning to the question, to get the desired behaviour, you need to convert the first field to a number:

```
awk '+$1 > 3 { print $1 }' file
```

I am using the *unary plus* operator to convert the field to a number. Alternatively, some people prefer to simply add 0.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the awk user guide...

ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_8.html

> When comparing operands of mixed types, numeric operands are converted
>   to strings using the value of CONVFMT. ... CONVFMT's default value is
>   "%.6g", which prints a value with at least six significant digits.

So, basically they are all treated as strings, and "String" Happens to be greater than "3".

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that it used `CONVFMT`.